# How we can convert value of type ObservedObject to Binding in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I like to know how I can convert value of type `ObservedObject` to Binding, any idea?

my `DataView` needs `dataModel` to work, I am feeding it as usual but it is not usable! I need to convert

here my code:

```
import SwiftUI


class DataModel: ObservableObject

{
    @Published var data : String = "Hello, world!"
}


struct ContentView: View
{

@StateObject var dataModel = DataModel()

    
    var body: some View
    {
        
        DataView(dataModel: $dataModel)

    }
}



struct DataView: View
{
    
    @Binding var dataModel : DataModel

    var body: some View
    {
        Text(dataModel.data)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it as an `@ObservedObject`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var dataModel = DataModel()

    var body: some View {
        DataView(dataModel: dataModel)
    }
}

struct DataView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataModel: DataModel

    var body: some View {
        Text(dataModel.data)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

`DataModel` is a *class* so it's a reference type. Which means in the `DataView` you'll be using the same instance as in the `ContentView`.