# iOS SwiftUI - Cannot convert value of type ObservedObject

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this view:

```
struct CreateAccountButton : View {
    
    @Binding var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View{
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                viewRouter.currentPage = .register
            }
            
        }) {
            
            Text("create_account")
                .padding(.vertical)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .foregroundColor(Color("ColorText"))
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 0))
                
        }
        .background(Color("BtnGreenBG"))
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .padding(.top, 12)
    }
}
```

and I need to pass the viewRouter which I created in the mainview:

```
@StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
```

I tried:

```
CreateAccountButton(viewRouter: $viewRouter)
```

and get:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'ObservedObject<ViewRouter>.Wrapper' to expected argument type 'Binding<ViewRouter>'
```

I'm new to ios/swiftui and don't understand this error.

Based on this answer:

[How we can convert value of type ObservedObject to Binding in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64471919/how-we-can-convert-value-of-type-observedobject-to-binding-in-swiftui)

I changed

```
@Binding var viewRouter: ViewRouter
```

to

```
@ObservedObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
```

inside CreateAccountButton and it's still not working

SwiftUI/Swift is an unintuitive nightmare compared to Kotlin :(

Please help

Comment: Why do you have this router object? Doesnt look right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ObservableObject` is a reference type so we can just pass it by reference directly, binding is not needed.

```
struct CreateAccountButton : View {
    
    let viewRouter: ViewRouter     // << regular property

// if needed to observe it internally, ie. body (not closures) 
// contains router's property usage

//  @ObservedObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter


// ...
```

and call

```
CreateAccountButton(viewRouter: viewRouter) // inject reference
```

Answer (score 2):

Don’t pass the whole object, instead pass only a specific data of your vm.

```
CreateAccountButton(viewRouter: $viewRouter.currentPage)
```

And

```
@Binding var currentPage: Bool
```

In your CreateAccountButton.

Comment: I think I will have to create a new ViewRouter object inside CreateAccountButton then which will eliminate the purpose of ViewRouter, I switch between pages with it without that dumb default backtracking from NavigationView

Comment: NavigationView is necessary. You won’t be able to switch between pages with just a variable. Anything beside NavigationView is just stacks that stay on top of each other or sheets.

Comment: I use NavigationView passing viewRouter with which I can switch then between pages. With basic NavigationView I can't go from from page 1 to 2 and then from to 2 to 3 while closing 2 doing that, with viewRouter I can. In Andoid you can do that very easy without workarounds, ios development is absolutely dumb sometimes